# A specific calculation problem about 1D path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, path-integral

**Description**

In [Littlejohn's note 9](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1011/notes/pathint.pdf), the author deduce 1D propagator by using 1D path integral.
$$
K(x,x_0,t)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar\epsilon})^{N/2}\int {\rm d}x_1...{\rm d}x_{N-1}\times\exp\{\frac{i\epsilon}{\hbar}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}[\frac{m(x_{j+1}-x_j)^2}{2\epsilon^2}-V(x_j)]\}. \tag{25}
$$
After that, the author tries to simplify this formule by using stationary phase approximation, which means   we only consider about some path which are close to the classical path.

In the derivation of this formule, we need to calculate a matrix's determinant. The elements of this matrix are $$
Q_{kl}=2\delta_{kl}-\delta_{k+1,l}-\delta_{k-1,l}-\frac{\epsilon^2}{m}V^{\prime\prime}(x_k)\delta_{kl}-{\rm eq}.(66)
$$

In the following part of this note, the author translate this problem to a differential equation.
$$
m\frac{{\rm d}^2 F(\tau)}{{\rm d}\tau^2}=-V^{\prime\prime}(\bar{x}(\tau))-{\rm eq}.(76)
$$

Then the author skip some details and directly get the final result
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}{\rm det}Q_{kl}=-\frac{m}{\epsilon}(\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x\partial x_0})^{-1}-{\rm eq}.(79)
$$

**Problem**

I don't really understand how to derive eq.(66) to eq.(79), especially the derivation from eq.(76) to eq.(79). I wish someone could tell me the specific details about this derivation.